# Find and Replace in formula google sheets appscipt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find and replace in formula with a appscript.

I have this code but it doesn't seem to do anything and it doesn't error so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tko1bZhfATVbtcDWa6XoAG0CxLUdoSPYa_vJ2wvEfhI/edit#gid=0)

```
function replace(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overview");
  var range = sheet.getRange("C1:C3" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i=0;i< formulas.length;i++) {
    if(typeof formulas[i] !== "undefined" && formulas[i] != ""){
      formulas[i][0] = formulas[i][0].replace("?TEST", "TEST");
      data[i][0] = formulas[i][0].toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `formulas[i][0].toString()` is put into `data[i][0]` at `data[i][0] = formulas[i][0].toString();`. In this case, the value is not put to the cell. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

If you want to put `formulas[i][0].toString()` to the cell by modifying your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
data[i][0] = formulas[i][0].toString();
```

#### To:

```
range.offset(i, 0, 1, 1).setFormula(formulas[i][0]);
```

#### Note:

- But, if you want to replace `?TEST` to `TEST` in the formulas, I think that [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) might be useful. When TextFinder is used, it becomes as follows.

  ```js
  function replace() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overview");
    var range = sheet.getRange("C1:C3" + sheet.getLastRow());
    range.createTextFinder("?TEST").matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith("TEST");
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution was much easier.